# Most concise way to write a CSS transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

**Is there a more concise way to write the following code?**

```
element{
    transition: all 700ms linear,
        transform 700ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.14, 1.5),
        background 700ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.14, 1.5);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to apply a diferent transition timing function to transform and background properties, while using a linear one for the rest of the properties. This is working right, but I'm trying to keep it as *DRY* as possible.

Comment: "DRY" = "Don't Repeat Yourself."

Comment: @AnupamBasak [DRY/Dont Repeat Yourself on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
In this particular case, it would mean avoiding the repetition of the cubic-bezier formula and durations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's not much you can do here. You could specify the transition duration separately:

```
element{
    transition: all linear,
        transform cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.14, 1.5),
        background cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.14, 1.5);
    transition-duration: 700ms;
}
```

But that's about it. You can't specify your custom curve only once due to the way comma-separated transition values work. The entire list of values is repeated in the order they were specified, rather than having the last value be repeated infinitely.

That is to say, if you do this:

```
element{
    transition-property: all, transform, background;
    transition-duration: 700ms;
    transition-timing-function: linear, cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.14, 1.5);
}
```

What happens is that the missing value for `transition-timing-function` is filled as `linear`, not your custom curve. The result will not match your intended transition for `background`.

And if you try to take advantage of that by changing the order of transition properties like so, such that the missing value for `background` takes on your custom curve instead:

```
element{
    transition-property: transform, all, background;
    transition-duration: 700ms;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.14, 1.5), linear;
}
```

What happens is that the `all` transition will *override* the `transform` transition, even though you specified it separately, because the `all` comes later and it includes any previously-listed properties.

Comment: Good catch about moving the duration outside! Great answer!

Answer (score 3):

Well, the most DRY way would be to use something like SASS and write a mixin, then use that instead of copy pasting that code everywhere.  Another suggestion I'll make is to avoid using `all`, and instead enumerate the properties you'd like animated via the linear transition.  While this might be more verbose, I'm willing to bet it'll be way more performant, especially if you ever put graphically demanding things like `box-shadow` into the element's style.

So, while your way would work, I feel like the more unique transitions you have, the more valuable this formulation becomes:

```
element {
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-property: all, background, transform;
    transition-timing-function: linear, cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.14, 1.5), cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.14, 1.5);
}
```

Of course, I recommended enumerating properties, to avoid costly and unsolicited animations.  In that case, something like this makes more sense:

```
element {
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-property: height, background, transform, width;
    transition-timing-function: linear, cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.14, 1.5), cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.14,1.5), linear;
}
```

**Edit: as mentioned by @BoltClock, I was wrong about everything below this bold text, so please disregard it.  The comma separated arguments are applied again the order they were originally specified - neither the first nor the last repeats for additional `transition-property` values.  I do still think what I said about not using `all` is important advice for performance and future proofed scoping though!**

Take note of how I ordered the arguments: if there are more arguments for `transition-property` than `transition-timing-function`, the all of the extra properties will default to the *first* value listed for `transition-property` as their default.  So, put a `linear` (default) value first, then enumerate all your unique timing functions to match the correct property, and then any properties you amend to the end (like `width`) will automatically default to `linear`!  So, even if you add 5 more properties to the end of your property list, only `background` and `transform` will have their unique `cubic-bezier` timing functions.  For example:

```
element {
    transition-duration: 2s;
    transition-property: height, background, transform, width, oneProp, twoProp, threeProp, etcProp;
    transition-timing-function: linear, cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.14, 1.5), cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.25, 0.14,1.5);
}
```

Everything in the above uses the `linear` timing function except `background` and `transform`.  I feel like this is a good compromise between performance and DRY CSS.  I made a jsFiddle for you to check out the various options - comment out the different CSS to try each way:

http://jsfiddle.net/530cumas/4/

Comment: Actually, as I mentioned in my answer, the list of values will be repeated in the order specified. It's stated here in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transitions It neither takes only the first or last value and repeats it for the rest of the transitions. But yes, the most efficient thing you can do by far is to avoid having to use `all` as far as possible.

Comment: Just tested it and you are absolutely right.  Will edit.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my CSS knowledge (after a quick google), your current method is the shortest (and, therefore, the most "DRY") way to do what you want. Granted, I'm not a CSS guru, so I could be totally wrong.

Comment: To [reviewers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6517195): This is a perfectly valid answer (though it may not look like so immediately), as the question asks "What is the most concise way to write this", and the answer is "You have the most concise way".